# Create a json file with the following structure from CSV file using python

Tags: python, json, converters

Hi I have a Csv file which goes like this

```
start_index end_index         Scalar           API
    0          30            zone0.pkl        zone0-0
    30         60            zone1.pkl        zone1-1
    60         65            zone2.pkl        zone2-2
```

I have to create a json file such that it is of the form below

```
{
    "channel1": {
        "0": [{
            "scalar": "/zone0.pkl",
            "api": "/model/zone0-0"
        }],
        "1": [{
            "scalar": "/zone0.pkl",
            "api": "/model/zone0-0"
        }]
    },
```

But I need to add some functionality i.e.. `start_index and end_index` of first row is 0 and 30. So the above should replicate 30 times (with "0" position changing from 0 to 30) and `"scalar" and "api"` should remain the same for the 30 files.

Now comes the second row which has `start index and end index` as 30 and 60.Now the above form should replicate 30 times with `"scalar" and "api"` changing into that of corresponding second row.

Similarly it has to do for all rows with the object replicating by `(end_index-start_index)` which need not be 30 always and the `"Scalar" and "api"` changing accordingly.I use **PYTHON**

If I have under-emphasised or over-emphasised any point let me know in the comments.

Comment: What is blocking you ? have you tried to code something ? if yes can you show us

Comment: My idea was to load the csv as a dataframe and then convert to json.I am stuck at how to replicate it to (end-start) times

Answer (score 1):

try

import json

```
def create_json(start, end, scalar, api):
    start_idx = start
    end_idx = end
    scalar = scalar
    api = api
    res = dict()
    res["channel1"] = dict()

    for i in range(start_idx, end_idx):
        res["channel1"][i] = {"scalar": scalar, "api": api}

    json_res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    return json_res

print(create_json(0, 30, "zone0.pkl", "zone0-0"))
print(create_json(30, 60, "zone1.pkl", "zone1-1"))
```

Comment: So what about next row?

Comment: well consider the above code to be a function, so you would pass start = 30, end = 60, scalar = "zone1.pkl", api = "zone2-2", I made an edit to my answer above

Comment: The "channel1"  repeats for every json object! and moreover I dont get it in desired form

Comment: There is also a curly bracket after every channel 2 ..i.e it looks like {"channel2" : { } ....}